# Already activated the license in Unity Hub but it said no actives license

Tags: unity-game-engine, licensing, hub

Unity Hub 3.4.1

Window 10

Free Unity Personal License

I updated Unity Hub to version 3.4.1 and cannot open any projects. It said "**No active licenses** To create and open projects, you need an active license". So I click **Manage licenses**, my license is still there!! This never happen to me before and before I update everything was fine.

At first I just return the license then add a new one because I use Unity free version and I thought this is no big deal. But It's not work.

So I tell Unity Support and they suggest me many solutions

1. Check if my Unity_lic.URF have Read and Write permissions allowed
2. uninstall the program completely (include delete **Unity_lic.URF** file in *C:\ProgramData\Unity*) -> restart my laptop -> re-install Unity Hub -> run as administrator -> add new license -> *NOT WORKED*
3. Check if MAC address randomization system is not enabled since every license only works when the same MAC address of your machine is in place. but my WiFi hardware doesn't support randomize IP feature.